# How do I get the latest pods using for labels using fabric8 kubernetes client after re-creating/replacing the deployment?

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, fabric8, kubernetes-deployment

I keep getting the older pods while listing pods (pods in older deployment) for a deployment after recreating the deployment (either by replace or delete and create), using this code:

```java
List<Pod> otelCollectorPods =
  client
    .pods()
    .inNamespace(LOGCOLLECTION_NAMESPACE)
    .withLabels(otelCollectorDeployment.getMetadata().getLabels())
    .list()
    .getItems();

for (Pod pod : otelCollectorPods) {
  String podName = pod.getMetadata().getName();
  
  InputStream outputJsonFileInputStream =
    client
      .pods()
      .inNamespace(LOGCOLLECTION_NAMESPACE)
      .withName(podName)
      .file("/otel-output/json-out.json")
      .read();

  // do something with the inputstream...
}
```

I have tried creating deployment using `createOrReplace` as well as `delete` and the `create`, nothing worked:

```java
client
  .apps()
  .deployments()
  .inNamespace(LOGCOLLECTION_NAMESPACE)
  .withName(otelCollectorDeployment.getMetadata().getName())
  .createOrReplace(otelCollectorDeployment);
```

--

```java
client
  .apps()
  .deployments()
  .inNamespace(LOGCOLLECTION_NAMESPACE)
  .withName(otelCollectorDeployment.getMetadata().getName())
  .delete();


client
  .apps()
  .deployments()
  .inNamespace(LOGCOLLECTION_NAMESPACE)
  .withName(otelCollectorDeployment.getMetadata().getName())
  .create(otelCollectorDeployment);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the pods are no existing (i.e they are not listed in the `kubectl get pods` command)?

Comment: None so far. I think I will have to use the pods list to get the logs for each, I was just wondering if I could use the similar strategy as the command I pasted in the question.